# SVN Integration With Eclipse and CRX (CQ 5.6)

Tags: eclipse, svn, aem, crx

I've managed to use FileVault with Eclipse Indigo to set up a local instance of my CRX. (Currently working with CQ 5.6) I would now like to set up an SVN server which maps my repository (currently a local folder, as I'm just testing how this works) to whatever I have checked out using the FileVault/Eclipse environment.

The goal is to have SVN to handle versioning etc on the local instance after which all final changes would be committed to CRX. Any idea on how to achieve this?

[This](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/crx/current/developing/development_tools/svn_integration.html/%22This%22) and [This](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/developmenttools/developing_with_eclipse.html/%22This%22) help to some extent, but I'm still struggling with mapping SVN to whatever is checked out by FileVault.

Additionally, what would be the best SVN server to utilize in this case? Currently using VisualSVN Server Manager, but I did remember reading somewhere that repositories created this way would not be accessible through TortoiseSvn!

Answer (score 0):

the thing to remember when adding a something checked out with filevault into svn is not to commit the .vlt files

Otherwise you can use any svn tool. i recommend http://tortoisesvn.net/ or if you want to do it from within eclipse check out subclipse http://subclipse.tigris.org/